# Splash Screen on Ionic 3 android platform not working

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I've been looking for an answer for like 3 days and can't find the answer for this, I have installed the plugin(cordova-plugin-splashscreen) and downgrade the plugin latest to 2.0.0, relocated my images and rename my folder /resources to /res, put it to platforms/android/src/main/res folder still nothing is working. here's my config.xml

```
<platform name="android">
    <allow-intent href="market:*" />
    <icon density="ldpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-ldpi-icon.png" />
    <icon density="mdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-mdpi-icon.png" />
    <icon density="hdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-hdpi-icon.png" />
    <icon density="xhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xhdpi-icon.png" />
    <icon density="xxhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxhdpi-icon.png" />
    <icon density="xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxxhdpi-icon.png" />
    <splash density="land-ldpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-land-ldpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="land-mdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-land-mdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="land-hdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-land-hdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="land-xhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-land-xhdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="land-xxhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-land-xxhdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="land-xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-land-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="port-ldpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-port-ldpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="port-mdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-port-mdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="port-hdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-port-hdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="port-xhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-port-xhdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="port-xxhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-port-xxhdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="port-xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-port-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />
</platform>
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" spec="^2.0.0" />
```

Comment: Your `config.xml` file is pointing to files in the `resources` folder. So why would you put your images in a `res` folder? What is the actual problem? When you create a new Ionic project, the splashscreen works out of the box...

Comment: just trying everything, relocate and change my config.xml though. i have tried it to create new project and it works but i dont know why my project did not work on it. by the way it works on IOS platform

Comment: You don't explain you problem clearly: what is not working? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: i want splash screen to be working on my project in android but on IOS it is working fine

Answer (score 0):

When you create a new project from the CLI like for example:

```
ionic start testProject blank
```

you get a default splashscreen that works.

Add platforms:

```
ionic cordova platform add android

ionic cordova platform add ios
```

Don't change anything except for the `splash.png` image in the `\resources` folder.

Then run the command:

```
ionic resources
```

This will create all the resources and put them in the correct folders for all paltforms and update the `config.xml` file.

Run the project on your Android device:

```
ionic cordova run android --device
```

Comment: it works on a new project but im currently using my old project ionic 3 but still not wokring from it

Answer (score 0):

Use cordova-plugin-splashscreen version 4.0.1.
  config.xml

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" spec="~4.0.1"/>
<platform name="android">
    <allow-intent href="market:*"/>
    <icon density="ldpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-ldpi-icon.png"/>
    <icon density="mdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-mdpi-icon.png"/>
    <icon density="hdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-hdpi-icon.png"/>
    <icon density="xhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xhdpi-icon.png"/>
    <icon density="xxhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxhdpi-icon.png"/>
    <icon density="xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxxhdpi-icon.png"/>
    <splash density="land-ldpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-ldpi-screen.png"/>
    <splash density="land-mdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-mdpi-screen.png"/>
    <splash density="land-hdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-hdpi-screen.png"/>
    <splash density="land-xhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xhdpi-screen.png"/>
    <splash density="land-xxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xxhdpi-screen.png"/>
    <splash density="land-xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xxxhdpi-screen.png"/>
    <splash density="port-ldpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-ldpi-screen.png"/>
    <splash density="port-mdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-mdpi-screen.png"/>
    <splash density="port-hdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-hdpi-screen.png"/>
    <splash density="port-xhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xhdpi-screen.png"/>
    <splash density="port-xxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxhdpi-screen.png"/>
    <splash density="port-xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxxhdpi-screen.png"/>
  </platform>
```

Put the images in your project resource folder
[image]

Delete your www folder and try to run again

Hopefully it will work.

Comment: it's already been there... and just tried to change it on platforms/android/src/main/res